# How to send a proactive message from a bot to a user

Tags: botframework, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a message from a bot to a teams user who hasn't already installed the bot and doesn't need to install the bot via REST API.

I have tried following this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#starting-a-personal-conversations).

It clearly states:
"Sending a message to start a new conversation thread is different than sending a message in response to an existing conversation: when your bot starts a new a conversation, there is no pre-existing conversation to post the message to. In order to send a proactive message you need to:"

As far as I understand, this means that what I am trying to do is possible. I have tried to run this [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage).

However, as far as I can tell it needs a conversation id. Without a conversation id it doesn't work.

I have tried to send a request like this with a bot network token ( which is normally used to respond to an activity request by the user):

```
POST /v3/conversations
{
  "bot": {
    "id": "28:10j12ou0d812-2o1098-c1mjojzldxcj-1098028n ",
    "name": "The Bot"
  },
  "members": [
    {
      "id": "29:012d20j1cjo20211"
    }
  ],
  "channelData": {
    "tenant": {
      "id": "197231joe-1209j01821-012kdjoj"
    }
  }
}
```

However, it fails with the following message:

```
Send Message to https://graph.microsoft.com/v3/conversations failed: (401) {
  "error": {
    "code": "InvalidAuthenticationToken",
    "message": "Access token validation failure. Invalid audience.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "92922235-8c87-47ed-92bc-4ba17469611a",
      "date": "2019-09-24T14:43:59"
    }
  }
}
```

I am guessing that this maybe because I didn't send MicrosoftAppCredentials.TrustServiceUrl first. But this is a c# call. How do I make the same call in REST API?

Comment: Seems like you are using the old sample. Can you try using the latest v4 [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/16.proactive-messages) and see if the issue still persists?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Bot Framework REST APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0) documentation.

Here are steps to [generate the access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-quickstart?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#get-token) which you could use to call [Create Conversation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#create-conversation) APIs.

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=MICROSOFT-APP-ID&client_secret=MICROSOFT-APP-PASSWORD&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.botframework.com%2F.default
```

Comment: @wajees - msft. I have tried this. See the lower part of my original question. I always get an invalidauthenticationtoken error.

Comment: I have also tried just GET on /v3/conversation ( without the continuation token). It fails with the same error. I'm not sure how to obtain the cotinuation token.

Comment: Is [proactive messaging sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/v3-sdk-samples/CSharp/core-proactiveMessages/simpleSendMessage) code woking for you?

Comment: Yes, but the code needs an existing conversation to work. It isn't really 'proactive'.

Comment: In order to send Proactive message to any user, you need to know serviceUrl, tenantId and user's unique Id as documented in [Obtain necessary user information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bot-conversations/bots-conv-proactive#obtain-necessary-user-information) section.